# Python scipy curve_fit Exponential equation not fitting as expected

Tags: python, scipy, exponential, sas-jmp

I have data I am trying to fit a exponential to, this data is not ideal however when use JMP's in-build curve fit function it works as expected and a I get a good approximation of my data (please see bellow figure, JMP Fit Curve Exponential 3P).

[JMP Fit Curve Exponential 3P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNkbJ.png)

I am know trying to replicate this using the python  library scipy.optimize with the curve_fit function as described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). However this is producing very different curves please see bellow.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = ',' ,index_col = None, engine='python')

def exponential_3p(x, a, b, c):
    return a + b * np.exp(c * x) 

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exponential_3p,df.x,df.y)

a = popt[0] 
b = popt[1]
c = popt[2]

plt.plot(df.x,df.y)
plt.plot(df.x,exponential_3p(df.x, a, b, c))
```

[scipy optimize.curve_fit Exponential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KAwU.png)

Comment: You fit an exponential curve, which usually needs a good initial guess to achieve accurate fit. Other approach is to take the log of the function that you are fitting.

Comment: Any Idea how to achieve a good initial guess ? for Asymptote the mean should be close enought but not sure about the scale or growth rate b/c ?

Answer (score 1):

You are yet another victim of the incomprehensible stupidity of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

Curve-fitting and local optimization problems **REQUIRES** initial values for all variable parameters.  They are not optional.  There is no "default value" that makes sense.  `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` lies to you about this and allows you to not provide initial values and silently (not even a warning!) assumes that you meant all initial values to be 1.  This is wrong, wrong, wrong.

You must give sensible starting values or the fit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, with p) = [-0.26,0.0018,-2.28] i achieve the correct fit, however i need a way to achieve these initial values automatically in my case a/Asymptote a good guess here would be the mean or average of the last 10 values i was thinking. The polarity of c/growth rate could be acquired by subtracting y[-1] - y[0] however it s magnitude I'm not sure how to guess this. I'm also at a loss for what to do with b/scale.